# Qt QJSEngine import js files

Tags: javascript, qt, import, qjsengine

Is it possible to import javascript files in a QJSEngine (QT 5.6)?

**Example 1:**

Text in plainTextEdit:

```
.import "./jsimport.js" as Test
var x = Test.y;
console.log(x);
```

c++:

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    QJSEngine engine;
    engine.installExtensions(QJSEngine::AllExtensions);

    QJSValue result = engine.evaluate(ui->plainTextEdit->toPlainText());
    qDebug() << "isError:" << result.isError();
    qDebug() << "resultString:" << result.toString();
    if(result.hasProperty("lineNumber"))
        qDebug() << "property lineNumber:" << result.property("lineNumber").toInt();
}
```

text in jsimport.js file:

```
var y = 42;
```

result:

```
isError: true
resultString: "ReferenceError: Test is not defined"
property lineNumber: 2
```

**Example 2:**

Text in PlainTextEdit:

```
.import "./jsimport.js"
```

same c++ code

result:

```
isError: true
resultString: "SyntaxError: File import requires a qualifier"
property lineNumber: 1
```

It seems that there is some functionality for an import, because of the last error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The .import statement does not work with QJSEngine.
QJSEngine is just a bare interpreter, if you want to have some "import" functionality you might switch to QQmlEngine, which is built on top of QJSEngine:
http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-syntax-imports.html#qml-import-path

With QJSEngine you basically need to manually populate the js global object (and QtCreator sintax checker will not recognize the statements you use across the different files).

Comment: oh ok. Can i use the QQmlEngine for just javascript?

Comment: I don't know, nor can I point you to some example of that. In my project I ended up using QJSEngine and it works just fine as long as you don't expect it to have Qml features.

Comment: Might be because the answer is old, but QJSEngine does support imports: https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-5.12/qjsengine.html#evaluating-scripts

Comment: @Michael I assume `import` probably was added as part of the ES6 and ES7 update in Qt5.12: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/whatsnew512.html#qt-qml-module

Answer (score 1):

In newer Qt versions, `import` can be used in `QJSEngine`.

**Use ECMA-262/ES6 syntax instead of QML leading-dot syntax:**

```
import { Test } from "./jsimport.js"
var x = Test.y;
console.log(x);
```

**./jsimport.js**

```
export Test = {
  y: 54
}
```

I believe this was probably added as part of the upgrade to ES6 and ES7 in Qt5.12:

> - [The JavaScript engine now supports ECMAScript 7. This includes an upgrade to ECMAScript 6, see ECMAScript 6 - New Features: Overview & Comparison.](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/whatsnew512.html#qt-qml-module)
> - [ECMAScript modules can now be loaded directly with QJSEngine::importModule() and imported in .qml files when using the .mjs file extension.](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/whatsnew512.html#qt-qml-module)

As it says, you may also use `::importModule()` to preload/initialize ES6 modules from the C++ side.